# Why can't i come back to older working version of php after ugrade with error log on php 7.2 and 7.3

Tags: mysql, errors

I'm getting locked out of */wp-admin/ there is an error log. Its after changing php 7.2 to php 7.3. The error doesn't disappear even if i go back to php 5.6 where MySQL_connect function exists and is used.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in
>   /home/punkmmur/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1564 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/punkmmur/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php(592):
>   wpdb->db_connect() #1
>   /home/punkmmur/public_html/wp-includes/load.php(409):
>   wpdb->__construct('punkmmur_calyps...', '7S4T]52!pg',
>   'punkmmur_calyps...', 'localhost') #2
>   /home/punkmmur/public_html/wp-settings.php(106): require_wp_db() #3
>   /home/punkmmur/public_html/wp-config.php(93):
>   require_once('/home/punkmmur/...') #4
>   /home/punkmmur/public_html/wp-load.php(37):
>   require_once('/home/punkmmur/...') #5
>   /home/punkmmur/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(31):
>   require_once('/home/punkmmur/...') #6
>   /home/punkmmur/public_html/wp-admin/index.php(10):
>   require_once('/home/punkmmur/...') #7 {main} thrown in
>   /home/punkmmur/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1564

Restoring website does not work. I disabled all plugins via phpmyadmin and by renaming folders in ftp. I changed theme to default too. Now even if i come back to my theme, some pages stay stuck on default theme even if i clear browser cache. Website is accessible: [Tatouage Calypso, Tattoo Québec.](https://tatouagecalypso.com)I can't access [wp-admin](https://tatouagecalypso.com/wp-admin/) Maria DB is up to date. I tried multiple restores. Wp super Cache is deactivated i even trued to define to false the wp-cache entry in `wp-config.php`, i even added site url and home url in `wp-config.php`. I tried renaming .htaccess, i renamed theme directory to force fallback to default theme.

Comment: There error log is a _log_. It's still going to have the errors even if you fix the problem. The question is whether new errors are being added to the log.

Comment: It was always the same log that appeared i don’t know if it was added every time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was nd_mysqli php modules not activated for 7.2-7.3 but that still doesn’t explain why restore didn’t work once activated it worked but had some webmaster fix it for me. Maybe caching but i kept flushing caches.